# How do I delete a .txt file with TSQL, without using xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql-server, file, t-sql, delete-file

I am trying to use TSQL to delete a .txt file at the end of a process. My restriction is that I cannot use xp_cmdshell. I had tried using the undocumented xp_delete_file but from what I can find it will only delete SQLServer native .ldf or .bak files. 
Is there another approach that can be used? I am running in SQL server 2008 R2.

Comment: This would be called from a SQL Job. xp_xmdshell is disabled in out production environment. The existence of the .txt file is there to indicate to the job to move to the next step. I am pulling that through xp_fileexist This needs to run from the SQL job and not from SSIS per the requirements passed to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SQL Server Agent CmdExec job step? This can run "del"...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190264.aspx

In step 8 you'd have `del c:\importpath\toasted.txt`

Your comment to your question states you are running a "SQL job", so no need to overkill with CLR or sp_OA% solutions :-)

Comment: Your answer is better than mine :)

Comment: Yes good answer gbn, keep it simple. You could also do it in powershell: remove-item "c:\importpath\toasted.txt"

Comment: Thanks gbn. That worked. It was the obvious answer under my nose that I was missing. I used the powershell remove step.