# Is there any alternative to XP_CMDSHELL in to create files in MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, powershell, t-sql

I have a TSQL code through which I have to delete a text file, I was using this code:

```sql
SET @cmd2=''XP_CMDSHELL ''''DEL "C:\\Provision\\Logs\\FullBackup.txt"'''''';
```

But it is voiliting the STIG, so I want any alternative command to delete a file using TSQL script.
Is there any other command that can delete my file just like `XP_CMDSHELL`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I delete a .txt file with TSQL, without using xp\_cmdshell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830464/how-do-i-delete-a-txt-file-with-tsql-without-using-xp-cmdshell)

Comment: @rickjerrity I use the above code, however on running that it says specified job_name does not exist, so what do with that, where to create job name

Comment: Is it mysql or tsql, please remove unnecessary tags

Comment: What code are you running to get _specified job name does not exist?_ are you using `sp_start_job`? Did you create a SQL Server agent job first?